# docker support visual studio 2017 fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose, visual-studio-2017

I've been playing with docker for a while and was pleased to see the new tools in VS2017. I've had issues before with docker for windows but I can't see why this one is happening.

I create a webapp just straight from the box and add docker support. I then simply try and launch it with no changes and I get the following error.

[image: Error here]

I have checked that the container is registered and it does look to have gotten that far:

a quick `docker ps -a` yields this:

[image: docker output]

The thing is the error reporting appears to be trying to deploy from a build path does does indeed not exist (my projects are on my G drive not F, that is where visual studio is installed).

So what gives? I can run the docker-compose from the command line inside the project path and then `docker-compose up` and it seems fine. Seems visual studio is just using the incorrect path, not sure why.

Version in use are:

Docker for windows 17.04.0-ce-rc2-win6(10840)
Visual studio 2017: Version 15.1(26403.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked again which version of docker I was using and I was using from the edge stream. I fell back to stable and this issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turns out solution told above of reverting to Docker stable version solved it. With Edge version, the build looks for solution file in the VS IDE folder instead of current folder.